# Disable alt focus

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

I switch language layouts by pressing `Alt+Shift` and it's infuriating when after pressing alt my focus goes to some settings (especially in Skype)

Instead of staying in the text input it focuses `ALT` menu

[image: alt menu]

To get back i have to remember to press `ALT` again

How can I disable this functionality?

OS: **Linux Ubuntu 20.04**

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what "focus goes to some settings" mean? GTK has that "feature" and I'm afraid there is no disabling it. See for example http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/menusandtoolbars/

Comment: Does [How do I disable mnemonics in GTK3](https://askubuntu.com/q/76077) help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the file

```
~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini
```

and add the following to it

```
[Settings]
gtk-enable-mnemonics = 0
```

If you want the settings to apply to all users, you can put in `/etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` instead.

Restart the X session once done.

Adapted/Stolen from https://askubuntu.com/a/569310 (go there and give it an upvote!).

Comment: Does not work unfortunately :/

Comment: @dhvcc Then I wonder if Skype actually uses GTK or something else. Have you tried it in Firefox, for example?

Comment: Skype does not support firefox for the web version :c

Comment: @dhvcc I see, but I mean that Firefox uses GTK, so if you test the solution on Firefox (without Skype), it *should* work.